# Is Borel algebra generated by all $G_\delta$ sets?

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

I am wondering this since the Borel algebra is generated by all open sets, or by all closed sets, or by all half-open intervals. My questions:

1. However, is it also generated by all $G_\delta$ sets? Similar question for by $F_\sigma$ sets, or by the finitely many combinations, e.g., $G_{\delta\sigma\delta\sigma}$, which means countable intersections of $G_{\delta\sigma\delta}$ sets and so on, etc.
2. Trying to answer my Q1 for $G_\delta$ set: Firstly, an open set is also (generated by) a $G_\delta$ set. Now, if I have a $G_\delta$ set, then it is also formed by (intersections of) open sets. So the answer to my question is yes for $G_\delta$ set?
3. If Q2 is correct, can this be continued to $G_{\delta\sigma\delta\sigma...\delta}$ and still result in the answer "yes"?

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Al, your classes include either the collection of all open sets or   the collection of all closed sets and hence they generate the Borel sigma algebra.

Comment: Is this in the real line?  Or, at least, is this a metric space?  If so, every open set is a $G_\delta$, so your answer is YES.  But what if  this is not a metric space?

Comment: @GEdgar I think I mean it is just $\mathbb{R}^n$, or yeah, a general metric space.

Comment: Of course, such an important stipulation should be included in the question.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So all of those collections just generate the same thing, which we call Borel sets, right?

Comment: @GEdgar Based on the  first sentence, where OP says Borel sigma algebra is generated by half-open intervals I assumed that the basic space to be just the real line.

Comment: @GEdgar Probably because I am not aware of any other spaces where we can talk about Borel algebra and thought this is common. If any exception exists, adding responses such as "In the context of ..., this does/does not hold because ..." is preferred, helping OP's unawareness as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted, any open set is by definition a $G_{\delta}$ set and a closed set is a $F_{\sigma}$ set. Hence, the Borel $\sigma-$algebra, $\mathscr{B}$ is of course contained in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $G_{\delta}$ sets, say $\mathscr{C}$ i.e. $\mathscr{B} \subset \mathscr{C}$.  But note that any $G_{\delta}$ set is contained in $\mathscr{B}$ and thus $\mathscr{C} \subset \mathscr{B}$ hence $\mathscr{C} = \mathscr{B}$.

Same argument works for your second question

Comment: The OP did not say this is a metric space.  And it not, then we cannot say "any open set is a $G_\delta$".

Comment: @GEdgar Well, OP's reply to your comment clears the air.

Comment: So everything above that I talk about actually just generates the same thing which is Borel algebra? Can't believe I missed this haha thanks!